# How to change the Android emulator temporary directory

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to know how to change it on WINDOWS ?

Because my C:/ drive don't have enought space to support all TMP file generated !

By default, here are the temp directory on WINDOWS: (%temp%) -> C:\Documents and Settings\MyPC\Local Settings\Temp\ and extract the file on (AndroidEmulator) folder ...

On Linux here the method: http://stuf.ro/how-to-change-the-android-emulator-temporary-directory

But i am looking for way to do it on windows :(

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You can follow [Possible to change where Android Virtual Devices are saved?][1]. May be get you solution from this.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841766/possible-to-change-where-android-virtual-devices-are-saved

Comment: No it's not same, .android are another story :) thank you for your time, i search to modify %temp% directly to another one :)

Answer (score 8):

I found on linux I can just set the ANDROID_TMP environment variable to a different directory.
Have you tried that ?

Comment: It does not work. The temp folder seems to be hardcoded in the adb binary.

Comment: Totally works for me. "ANDROID_TMP=/path/to/tmp emulator -avd Test".

Answer (score 3):

A solution could be to make a symbolic link to another location :

```
mklink /J "C:\Users\{you}\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator" "{new-location}"
```